# Can't push my node.js app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express

I can't seem to push my updated repository to Heroku. It worked before and the app is live right now on Heroku, but I can't push updates to it.

I've tried npm update, bower update, reinstalling Heroku-toolbelt, pushing while on a different network, pulling from heroku master, and force pushing to heroku master, git pull --rebase, npm cache clean, bower cache clean, uninstalling karma, updating npm on heroku and cleaning the cache on heroku.

I have multiple Heroku accounts which I manage with Heroku Accounts (https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts) as well as multiple git accounts, but I made sure I was on the correct ones.

Here is the last few lines from the terminal before failing to push:

```
3530 verbose rebuildBundles   'npmconf',
3530 verbose rebuildBundles   'rimraf',
3530 verbose rebuildBundles   'which' ]
3531 info install phantomjs@1.9.7-5
3532 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
3533 info phantomjs@1.9.7-5 Failed to exec install script
3534 error phantomjs@1.9.7-5 install: `node install.js`
3534 error Exit status 1
3535 error Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.7-5 install script.
3535 error This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
3535 error not with npm itself.
3535 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
33535 error     node install.js
3535 error You can get their info via:
3535 error     npm owner ls phantomjs
3535 error There is likely additional logging output above.
3536 error System Linux 3.8.11-ec2
3537 error command "/tmp/build_4600dbd4-687a-4b9c-bf9a-71e3baf5a1c4/vendor/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_4600dbd4-687a-4b9c-bf9a-71e3baf5a1c4/vendor/node/bin/npm" "rebuild"
3538 error cwd /tmp/build_4600dbd4-687a-4b9c-bf9a-71e3baf5a1c4
3539 error node -v v0.10.29
3540 error npm -v 1.4.14
3541 error code ELIFECYCLE
3542 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

To git@heroku.personal:myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.personal:myapp.git'
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's been a while and nobody has commented or asked for more information. So I'm kind of at a loss of ideas here. Does anyone know how I can check the logs or anything to get more information on the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I didn't get any answers here on StackOverflow, I posted my question on Heroku support.
The problem was coming from phantomjs, I removed it from my dependencies and moved it to devDependencies. After that, I purged my build cache using the heroku-repo plugin https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo

Then I could push to Heroku again

Comment: Could you link to your Heroku support question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/avizbWg9
There was a link to the Heroku-repo plugin that I provided in the original answer.
I can't link to it because Heroku support is private to the user, so here is a pastebin of the conversation